# how to consume string from middle and show in UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have an String that is "WAKEFIELD - TRINITYIGINY - (3.15 miles)" that need to display like this in a UILabel.That means char is consume from middle.

[image]

Note that,it should be dynamic and need to display into UITableViewCell.The strings length is not fix.It is clear that,its only string.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UILabel has a property for truncation (lineBreakMode)
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html

If you set it to `NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle`it will truncate in the middle.

Comment: @Md.shohrabhossainChowdhury Don't forget to click the checkmark next to this answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can yet the components from your original string using `[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "]`, then you get an array. Then, create three UILabel with different font in your cell and set `lineBreakMode` for the second.
If you want to create this three label with cellWidth, you probably creates your cellWidth, you put your first label to the left side of the cell, the third to the right side, and you have some place left in the middle probably. This is the place of your second label. You can calculate the size of your first and third label:

```
 CGSize labelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:maxPossibleSizeOfTheLabel];
```

Comment: I have tried this procedure.but it cross the table cell limit when string is too long.please notice i need to consume char from middle of string to fix into cell.thanks

Comment: Ok, now I understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`lineBreakMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/lineBreakMode) property of UILabel:

```
UILabel *label = ...
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;
```